# Rails find where HABTM association is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have `Popup` and `User` that have a HABTM association.

I am trying to write a scope for `Popup` that would look like: `Popup.not_seen_by(current_user).first`

Unfortunately, my implementation below doesn't work.  I feel like I'm on the right track, would anyone be willing to help me get over this last hurdle?

```
class Popup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :uniq => true

  scope :not_seen_by, lambda { |user| 
    # This does NOT work
    joins("LEFT JOIN popups_users ON popups.id = popups_users.popup_id").
    where("popups_users.user_id != ?", user.id)
  }
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right track, but you are joining to every single row in popups_users that has a matching popup_id (i.e. a row that does not contain your user_id), and so returning multiple instances of the same popup. this should be what you're looking for:

```
scope :not_seen_by, lambda { |user| where('id NOT IN (select popup_id 
                                                  from popups_users 
                                                  where user_id = ?)',user.id) }
```

Not quite sure why my original 'IN' version didn't work. NOT IN is usually pretty slow, so you might want to try this too which should be equivalent and may be faster:

```
scope :not_seen_by, lambda { |user| where('NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                                                  from popups_users
                                                  where popups_users.popup_id = popups.id
                                                  and user_id = ?)',user.id) }
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without a sub-select?  Or is the fastest SQL way to do it?

Comment: OK, I changed it to `where('id NOT IN (select popup_id from popups_users where user_id = ?)',user.id)` and that worked.  If you updated your answer I'll mark it as correct.